# Is attending a property transaction where buyer is getting loan forbidden?

Tags: quran, sharia, riba

What I have read till now is indulging in ribs in anyway is forbidden, be it taking, giving, making contract, executing or being witness.

My questions:

1. What if I do not facilitate loan but get muslim buyers who are willing to take loan on their own...can I work for just seller in that case?
2. As a real estate agent can I attend the closure meeting from seller side while muslim buyer is getting bank loan on its own? Will I become a witness?

Comment: I don't see a reason why this would be forbidden, since the stores and malls or restaurant we visit are ran on loans with high interest rates (riba). I will be researching this more and let you know soon or someone else on this site might.

Comment: @nana adam....sure I'll wait for your answer.